# Perl-Using same variable for nested loops considered improper?

Tags: perl

In a for loop I usually do this:

```
for my $i (0 .. 6){
###stuff to loop
}
```

Though, is it recognized as improper usage if I use $i multiple times? 
eg:

(These loops are purposely nested together)

```
for my $i (0 .. 6){
###some stuff
    for my $i (0 .. 30){
    ###double looped ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using different variable names to if you have to use more then one index, it is easier to track what is occurring and probably more helpful in debugging if something does not work correctly.

Comment: Did you mean to make those for loop nested? Or is that just a typo?

Comment: @TLP It was on purpose, sorry for not clarifying that.

Comment: @Shortland You should use indentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is quite possible to write code like that, using nested loops with the same name on the iterator, and it is what happens when you use the default variable `$_`. Whether you *should* do it is another question.

What happens is that the variables become localized.

```
for my $i (1 .. 2) {
    # $i == 1 or 2
    for my $i (3 .. 4) {
    # $i == 3 or 4
    }
    # $i returns to the old value 1 or 2
}
```

If you use the same variable name in a nested loop, you cannot access the loop iterator of the outer loop inside the inner loop. So in answer to your question, if not improper, it is rather impractical. And I assume that with less experienced programmers, it can lead to confusion, so in that sense, I would say it was not a good idea.

Comment: They were purposely nested together, sorry for not clarifying that.